# Stop implicit commiting in lodash chain

Tags: javascript, lodash

Until today I thought lodash chain "collapses" by explicitly calling `.value()`. However, I've been proven wrong by a snippet below

```js
(function(undefined) {
  var a = { a: 'a', b: 'b' };
  var chain = _(a);
  chain.pick('b');
  
  // > { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
  console.log(chain.value());

  chain = _(a).pick('b');
  
  // > { b: 'b' }
  console.log(chain.value());
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to turn off implicit chain commiting?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Can you provide some context?

Comment: `chain.pick('b')` doesn't mutate `chain` but returns something to be used in the chain. But here, this value is just ignored / lost. That's what you show in your self answer, where you use this returned value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. It's just how chains work.

But you can `plant` (clone) a chain.

[From the docs:](https://lodash.com/docs#prototype-plant)

```
var array = [1, 2];
var wrapped = _(array).map(function(value) {
    return Math.pow(value, 2);
});
var other = [3, 4];
var otherWrapped = wrapped.plant(other);
otherWrapped.value(); // → [9, 16]
wrapped.value(); // → [1, 4]
```

Comment: Plant is useless for me, but maybe for someone else it will be ok. I thought the chain instance kept track of new chain elements, but it doesn't. It's just so the each next element knows of previous chain element, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

If @HNeiva answer doesn't suit your cause, you can simply overwrite your old chain with latest wrapper:

```js
(function(undefined) {
  var a = { a: 'a', b: 'b' };
  var chain = _(a);
  chain = chain.pick('b');
  
  // > { b: 'b' }
  console.log(chain.value());
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```